# Tensorflow game does not learn

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

i got a little one-file game (without pygame or any other stuff needed) that i run with a DQN.

Now i got everything, but the strange thing is, the network does right from beginning (without random actions) play better then with random actions at the beginning ? OK, it only needs to go to the left or to the right. It needs to learn to change the direction while it is playing, but it seemed to only change the bias always, to simply run to the left or to the right, but it does not learn anymore ?

If you run the game in console, you see directly after 3 minutes that all weights dont change anymore, only the bias ?

I changed the mini-batch-size, observation_steps, learning_rate  and nothing change dramatically. What else could i change or do ?

[pixel hunter tensorflow game](https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_tensorflow_game/blob/master/pixel_hunter_game/flobotics_game.py)

Comment: Hard to understand the problem without a bit more context

Comment: hi @fabrizioM  thats why i put this simple one-file-game which you simply can copy and run in console with "python flobotics_game.py"  . Then you see the game playing (small window with two white moving pixels) and can look with "tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/train" in webbrowser all hidden layer weights and biases.   I think , then its easy to understand, just run it :)